# Actualizar valor de input al cargar ventana modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente ventana modal que se genera mediante un script en línea:

```html
<div class="wompi-wbox-modal"><div class="wompi-wbox-modal-header"><h1>Pagar con Wompi</h1><a href="#close" class="wompi-wbox-closebutton"><svg role="img" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M207.6 256l107.72-107.72c6.23-6.23 6.23-16.34 0-22.58l-25.03-25.03c-6.23-6.23-16.34-6.23-22.58 0L160 208.4 52.28 100.68c-6.23-6.23-16.34-6.23-22.58 0L4.68 125.7c-6.23 6.23-6.23 16.34 0 22.58L112.4 256 4.68 363.72c-6.23 6.23-6.23 16.34 0 22.58l25.03 25.03c6.23 6.23 16.34 6.23 22.58 0L160 303.6l107.72 107.72c6.23 6.23 16.34 6.23 22.58 0l25.03-25.03c6.23-6.23 6.23-16.34 0-22.58L207.6 256z"></path></svg></a></div><div class="wompi-wbox-modal-content"><iframe src="https://pagos.wompi.sv/IntentoPago/Redirect?id=96591422-83c5-43a4-9062-cb1b20fe5846&amp;esWidget=1" class="wompi-wbox-modal-content-iframe" scrolling="no" style="height: 1422.75px;" title=" " frameborder="0"></iframe></div></div>
```

## Pagar con Wompi

Necesito actualizar el valor del input de precio al momento de cargar la ventana modal, algún alma bondadosa que me dé una luz de como hacerlo.

Les estaré muy agradecido.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que leo en la documentación:

https://docs.wompi.co/docs/en-us/widget-checkout-web

Para poder introducir el importe, deberías de cargar el widget de este modo:

```
<form>
  <script
    src="https://checkout.wompi.co/widget.js"
    data-render="button"
    data-public-key="pub_test_X0zDA9xoKdePzhd8a0x9HAez7HgGO2fH"
    data-currency="COP"
    data-amount-in-cents="4950000"
    data-reference="4XMPGKWWPKWQ"
    >
  </script>
</form>
```

Y no directamente con un `iframe`, en la documentación hay mas ejemplos, de como hacerlo mediante un botón.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu apoyo, pero ese widget aplica para Wompi Colombia, el que estoy usando es Wompi SV (El Salvador) y no ofrece ese widget, los clientes obtienen un client id y un private key, no un public key.